# How can I add a large JSON object to a header in Postman?

Tags: rest, header, postman

The SendGrid API needs some large JSON in the `X-SMTPAPI` custom header field.
How can I enter & edit this in Postman?

E.g.:

```
{
  "to": [
    "ben@sendgrid.com",
    "joe@sendgrid.com"
  ],
  "sub": {
    "%name%": [
      "Ben",
      "Joe"
    ],
    "%role%": [
      "%sellerSection%",
      "%buyerSection%"
    ]
  },
  "section": {
    "%sellerSection%": "Seller information for: %name%",
    "%buyerSection%": "Buyer information for: %name%"
  },
  "category": [
    "Orders"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be easy to do.

Just modify your postman header request as illustrated in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of header]